# (Induced) Surface charge/current density of dielectric material?

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider an incident $s$-wave traveling from vacuum to a linear dielectric material (at an angle), clearly there's no surface charge density since $\vec{E}$ has no normal component. However, we can get a surface current density from magnetization $\vec{M}$.

Isn't this violation of conservation of charge? And how's that possible?